Reading text from a picture
I have an image that for purely curiosity purposes I would like to read, I would also like to educate myself on how such complex images can be read for later analysis etc.
At first I tried to apply various filters, but the ocr is still unable to read the text.
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter, ImageOps,ImageEnhance
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

image_path = 'captcha.jpg'  
img = Image.open(image_path)

img_gray = img.convert('L')
img_blurred = img_gray.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(radius=1))

img_array = np.array(img_blurred)
threshold_value = 35  
img_array = np.where(img_array < threshold_value, 255, 0)  
img_thresholded = Image.fromarray(img_array.astype('uint8'))



img_cv = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img_thresholded), cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)


kernel = np.ones((6, 3), np.uint8)  
img_morph = cv2.morphologyEx(img_cv, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)  


img_morph_pil = Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(img_morph, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY))

enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(img_morph_pil)
img_contrasted = enhancer.enhance(5)  
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img_morph_pil, config='--psm 7')  
print(text)
img_morph_pil.show()



what is the ouptut that you get, i.e. of print(text), and what is your question?

displays invalid text, or no text at all. I am therefore asking for help to solve the problem so that the image becomes readable for tesserac

These kind of images were specifically designed, so that traditional OCR algorithms cannot read them (captcha). I don't know which algorithm Tesseract uses internally here, but I guess, a more sophisticated OCR algorithm may be required in this case, such as an appropriately trained deep neural network.

I would go with the following approach:

Noise reduction using Non-Local Means Denoising
Adaptive thresholding instead of global thresholding, which handles varying lighting conditions better.
Perspective correction for skewed text
Character segmentation enhancement
Contour analysis to remove small noise
Custom OCR configuration with character whitelist

Here is an example snippet that you could implement in your code:
# Load image
    image_path = 'captcha.jpg' 
    img = cv2.imread(image_path)

# Convert to grayscale
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# 1. Noise reduction
    denoised = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(gray)

# 2. Adaptive thresholding
    thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(
        denoised, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, 
        cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2)

# 3. Dilation to connect components
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (2, 2))
    dilated = cv2.dilate(thresh, kernel, iterations=1)

# 4. Advanced preprocessing
    # Remove small noise
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(
        dilated, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE
    )
    mask = np.ones(dilated.shape, dtype=np.uint8) * 255
    for contour in contours:
        if cv2.contourArea(contour) < 100:  # Adjust threshold as needed
            cv2.drawContours(mask, [contour], -1, 0, -1)
    cleaned = cv2.bitwise_and(dilated, mask)

# 5. Perspective correction (if needed, test this)
    def get_perspective_transform(img):
        coords = np.column_stack(np.where(img > 0))
        angle = cv2.minAreaRect(coords)[-1]
        if angle < -45:
            angle = 90 + angle
        (h, w) = img.shape[:2]
        center = (w // 2, h // 2)
        M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1.0)
        rotated = cv2.warpAffine(
            img, M, (w, h), flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC, 
            borderMode=cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE
        )
        return rotated
    
    aligned = get_perspective_transform(cleaned)

# 6. Character segmentation enhancement
    kernel_vertical = np.ones((3,1), np.uint8)
    kernel_horizontal = np.ones((1,3), np.uint8)
    
    # Enhance vertical strokes
    vertical_lines = cv2.erode(aligned, kernel_vertical, iterations=1)
    vertical_lines = cv2.dilate(vertical_lines, kernel_vertical, iterations=1)
    
    # Enhance horizontal strokes
    horizontal_lines = cv2.erode(aligned, kernel_horizontal, iterations=1)
    horizontal_lines = cv2.dilate(horizontal_lines, kernel_horizontal, iterations=1)
    
    # Combine enhanced features
    enhanced = cv2.addWeighted(vertical_lines, 0.5, horizontal_lines, 0.5, 0)
    
    # 7. Final cleanup
    final = cv2.medianBlur(enhanced, 3)
    
    # OCR Configuration
    custom_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 6 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
    
    # Extract text
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(final, config=custom_config)

Best way to learn image processing is through trail and error, as you'll see that different images have different features.

thank you, but I have tried testing different values and I still can't manage to read it :/

As I said, it's trial and error. You can add a statistical model for approximation, or use DNN to distinguish what letter it is. Maybe your eye can catch that the first letter is M because it's know to you, but how would you tell the software to distinguish it? Think of it that way, and it is possible to find a way to detect it.
